# Adding fade to changing tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs, fade

So I am using a tab system for some content, but would like to animate it slightly. As it is, the tabs work exactly as they should. Click a tab, content changes. tada! BUT, what I would like to know is if its possible to have the tabs fade into view rather than just pop in, and when the content with the div grows or shrinks, it animates while doing so.

This is the code I am using:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content = $($active.attr('href'));
                $links.not($active).each(function () {
                    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                });

                $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                    $active.removeClass('active');
                    $content.hide();

                    $active = $(this);
                    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content.show();

                    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        });
```

I've tried referencing one of my earlier questions regarding fading things out on .removeclass, but that didn't work out. So far I've tried adding in various bits that I thought would work (.fadeIn(500) on the .addclass) but I've had results that were...not good. I've made the menu disappear randomly, had the tabs disappear entirely, and one of my cats threw up. Not sure if thats connected though, to be fair.

Would anyone be able to land a hand here? Thanks much in advance.

Comment: I'd apply CSS3 transitions to the style changes. Shouldn't need to script it. Put your example in a fiddle and we'll take a look. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I actually sort of figured it out, as the code below shows. Only thing is that the div doesn't quite grow nicely to fit the content, but its not horrible either. The fade part works. 

I worry about using the transitions just because of IE. A lot of our visitors are on older versions of IE so I have to try and support down to about 8. Anything earlier and they can suck it. :D

Answer (score 1):

nermind, figured it out! I noticed that it used .show so i replaced it with a .fadeIn and it works!

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content = $($active.attr('href'));
                $links.not($active).each(function () {
                    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                });

                $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                    $active.removeClass('active');
                    $content.fadeOut(300);

                    $active = $(this);
                    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content.delay(300).fadeIn(500);

                    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        });
```

Woot! Learning!